# Refresh POT in PoEdit

Tags: localization, internationalization, poedit

I created a POT to translate my website and generated a MO file.

I created a new project and improted from POT file, during the translation I noticed a few errors on my original POT.

I made the corrections and now I want to "refresh" the POT file, to update my translation project without lossing all the translation I've done.

How can I do  this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `msgmerge`. Everything is explained in the [GNU gettext manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html).

Comment: `msgmerge old.po new.pot` does it... But I can't do it using PoEdit?

Comment: Well, that one is done by Catalog -> Update from POT file... But you said you wanted to refresh the POT file (which involves `xgettext`), not *from* the POT file (which is what the command in your comment does).